# How to calculate count of particular day between two dates?

Tags: ios, iphone, date, calendar

I want total count of particular day between two dates.I want to make one function that return total count of particular day.
For example: If i pass Monday , start date and end date then it will return total count of Monday between these dates.

If i pass day as Monday and start date 2014-10-04 and end date is 2014-10-18 then function should be return count of Monday is 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution my self

```
-(int)countDays:(int)dayCode startDate:(NSDate *)stDate endDate:(NSDate *)endDate 
{

    // day code is Sunday = 1 ,Monday = 2,Tuesday = 3,Wednesday = 4,Thursday = 5,Friday = 6,Saturday = 7

    NSInteger count = 0;

    // Set the incremental interval for each interaction.
    NSDateComponents *oneDay = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [oneDay setDay:1];

    // Using a Gregorian calendar.
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSDate *currentDate = stDate;

    // Iterate from fromDate until toDate
    while ([currentDate compare:endDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {

        NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:currentDate];

        if (dateComponents.weekday == dayCode) {
            count++;
        }

        // "Increment" currentDate by one day.
        currentDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:oneDay
                                            toDate:currentDate
                                           options:0];
    }
    NSDateComponents* component = [calendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:endDate];
    int weekDay = [component weekday];
    if (weekDay == dayCode) { // Condition if end date contain your day then count should be increase
        count ++ ;
    }
    return count; // Return your day count
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i can tell u a simple logic to calculate. If it is monday(Start date A) the next monday will be 7 days later... So add 7 days to the start date and check whether the next date(Start Date B) is lesser than the End date if not again add 7 days to the (Start date B) again check whether this is lesser than the end date. Count it accordingly. do something like this

```
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [NSDateComponents new];
        dateComponents.day = 7;
        NSDate *DateWithAdditon = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents   toDate: StartDate
                                                                      options:0];

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
        NSString *DateWithAdditonString=  [ dateFormatter stringFromDate:DateWithAdditon];

        NSLog(@"your next monday will be here %@ ",DateWithAdditonString );


//Write code to check wheather the DateWith addition is lesser than the End date if not add another 7 days and increase the count accordingly
```